# How to resolve nxt-python error "ImportError: No module named 'nxt'"

Tags: python, python-idle, nxt, lego-mindstorms, nxt-python

I am attempting to use nxt-python in order to program a robot.

I installed nxt-python for mac by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Eelviny/nxt-python/wiki/Installation).

After installing it I decided to run one of the example scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import nxt.locator
from nxt.motor import *

def spin_around(b):
    m_left = Motor(b, PORT_B)
    m_left.turn(100, 360)
    m_right = Motor(b, PORT_C)
    m_right.turn(-100, 360)

//The print line was added by me.
print("Script Starting")
b = nxt.locator.find_one_brick()
spin_around(b)
```

I opened up the .py file with IDLE and clicked "Run -> Run Module". As I was running the script my NXT was turned on and connected by USB. I had also installed PyUSB.

However, I got the error `ImportError: No module named 'nxt'`

Since I successfully installed nxt-python, why would this occur?

Comment: Because you installed within python 2, you're running python 3,or vice versa

Comment: Another options is that your `idle` that you are running is not the same python that you run the installation on.

Comment: How do I check what version of python my idle is running?

Comment: In any Python or wrapper thereof, 2.x or 3.x, interactive or batch: `import sys; print(sys.version)`.

Comment: IDLE is not (at least, should not be) directly involved with this import error.  If you run your code with the same Python you use to run IDLE, you should see the same error.